# поиск двух одинаковых значений в двух различных массивах

Tags: массивы, flutter, dart, yaml

В настоящее время я пытаюсь связать два YAML-файла во Flutter.
Проблема в том, что один из YAML-файлов (например, amount.yaml) служит для хранения последовательности элементов (индекс), а другой (например, fruit_specification.yaml) - содержит информацию об элементах.

Вот пример:
fruit_specification.yaml:

```
fruit: 
    - name: apple
      color: red
      amount: 3
    - name: banana 
      color: yellow
      amount: 2
    - name: plum 
      color: purple 
      amount: 5
```

и второй YAML-файл amount.yaml:, который выполняет функцию навигации и распределения значений в заданной последовательности:

```
- amount: 2
- amount: 3
- amount: 5
```

Может быть есть у кого-то идеи, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В чем именно у вас сложность?

Comment: Я не так давно программирую, поэтому не особо понимаю как можно использовать два yaml файла в  ListView.builder к примеру, где последовательность элементов(DropdownButtonFormField) будет генерироваться и контролироваться через  один файл, а все значения(values, title) будут взяты с другого файла.

Comment: как вы описали - скорей всего никак, точнее стандартный билдер выкинуть и написать свой, в котором вы и опишите какие именно данные из какого файла, в каком порядке доставать и куда класть

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за ответ. Это, конечно, не то что мы бы хотели сделать, но мне  на данный момент тоже никакие идеи  не приходят.